# Good "frequent sequence mining" packages in Python?

Tags: python, sequential-pattern-mining

Has anyone used (and liked) any good "frequent sequence mining" packages in Python other than the FPM in MLLib? I am looking for a stable package, preferable stilled maintained by people. Thank you!

Comment: For that purpose, I don't think implementations in python or in R are going to help at all. Patterning libraties in R and Python do the least work only for frequent patterns but you you want to find some specific patterns other than frequent one, they are not going to be any help at all.

Answer (score 8):

I am actively maintaining an efficient [implementation](https://github.com/chuanconggao/PrefixSpan-py) of both PrefixSpan and BIDE in Python 3, supporting mining both frequent and top-k (closed) sequential patterns.

Comment: I'd like to implement those in javascript, but I don't fully understand how these algorithms work. Can you explain it in plain English?

Comment: I suggest you check my original minimal implementation of PrefixSpan. Its core part takes only 15 lines. https://gist.github.com/chuanconggao/4df9c1b06fa7f3ed854d5d96e2ae499f

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to translate it to js, but won't be easy. :-) Afaik PrefixSpan is building projected databases based on where the prefix matches. I am currently reading about BIDE, which is theory is an even better algorithm.

Comment: There are too many differences between js and python collections. I did not manage to reproduce the code in js. I'll try it again later.

Comment: Not sure whether it helps, but I have another Scala version of PrefixSpan. https://github.com/chuanconggao/PrefixSpan-scala However, I highly suggest you fully understand the algorithm before implement.

Comment: I just wanted to solve it in a copy paste manner, but you are right, I need to fully understand the code first to be able to translate it. I read about prefixspan a few days ago, it is not that hard, I already know the theory behind it. It's just that js does not have range and defaultdict, so I have to solve this with maps and arrays only. The iteration is different too especially with ES5. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @inf3rno It's not too different from A-priori. The only difference is that you also allow for recombining a frequent pattern with itself. An example, assume we have a tx database with rows 1) ABCD 2) AB 3) BD 4) AD) and min support=2. Then the first iteration: Candidate set 1(C(1)] will be the individual patterns: A, B, C and D. Support for each is 3,  3, 1, 3. So the set of Frequent items (1) will be A, B and D. C is pruned because it was not frequent. Now comes the part where it differs from A-priori from level 2 onwards. C(2) will be: AA, AB, AD, BB, BD, DD. Repeat til candidateset is empty

Comment: @user21398 Yes, I already coded PrefixSpan in JS since then. I read the scientific article about BIDE several times, but I did not fully understand its pseudocode. I think something was missing from the article, idk. I'll give it a try again later when I need it. I was thinking on my own algorithms too and I found that the definition of sequential pattern is not necessarily the best either.

Answer (score 5):

The only Python package I've found is on [Github](https://github.com/bartdag/pymining).

They have an implementation of `BIDE` there, but it's not maintained code.

Comment: Just to clarify, it did not implement BIDE which mines frequent closed sequences. It actually implemented PrefixSpan which mines all frequent sequences. PrefixSpan and BIDE share the same pattern enumeration framework, and that is why the authors cited the BIDE paper.

Comment: What I did in the end is used: http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/ - It's a JAVA lib but I've wrapped it with python to match my needs

Answer (score 2):

[SPMF](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/) sounds like a useful library for pattern mining.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered to write it by yourself? Because there is probably no up-to-date maintained library right now.

Check [this](http://sequenceanalysis.github.io/) out, its the basic - PrefixSpan and Closed/Maximal patterns are actually not that hard to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the existing solutions were satisfactory for me, I created [my own Python Wrapper](https://github.com/LoLei/spmf-py) for [SPMF (the Java library mentioned in other answers here)](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/).

Answer (score 1):

To complement some of the great answers/libraries:

[Seq2Pat: Sequence-to-Pattern Generation Library](https://github.com/fidelity/seq2pat) might be relevant to your case.

The library is written in Cython to take advantage of a fast C++ backend with a high-level Python interface. It supports **constraint-based** frequent sequential pattern mining.

Here is an example that shows how to mine a sequence database while respecting an average constraint for the prices of the patterns found.

```
# Example to show how to find frequent sequential patterns
# from a given sequence database subject to constraints
from sequential.seq2pat import Seq2Pat, Attribute

# Seq2Pat over 3 sequences
seq2pat = Seq2Pat(sequences=[["A", "A", "B", "A", "D"],
                             ["C", "B", "A"],
                             ["C", "A", "C", "D"]])

# Price attribute corresponding to each item
price = Attribute(values=[[5, 5, 3, 8, 2],
                          [1, 3, 3],
                          [4, 5, 2, 1]])

# Average price constraint
seq2pat.add_constraint(3 <= price.average() <= 4)

# Patterns that occur at least twice (A-D)
patterns = seq2pat.get_patterns(min_frequency=2)
```

Notice that sequences can be of different lengths, and you can add/drop other Attributes and Constraints. The sequences can be any string, as in the example, or integers.

The underlying algorithm uses [Multi-valued Decision Diagrams](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/vanhoeve/mdd/), and in particular, the [state-of-the-art algorithm from AAAI 20019](https://ojs.aaai.org//index.php/AAAI/article/view/3962).

Hope this helps!

Disclaimer: I am a member of the research collaboration between Fidelity & CMU on the [Seq2Pat Library](https://github.com/fidelity/seq2pat).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [fim](http://www.borgelt.net/pyfim.html)'s fpgrowth function in the past and it worked well.  It's kind of a pain to install on Windows machines however.  It seems to be an academic website so I'm not sure if they're doing many updates to the code over time...